# Firebase Realtime Database, note wont reappear after deleting data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a posts node, deleted all posts in the console now when creating new posts the node will no reappear

Hey, I am creating a mobile app, I was able to create posts and show them on the home screen. I was trying to sort them newest-oldest and i thought the porblem was that when i had created old posts that they didn't have the time on them so that why would not sort. so I deleted all the old posts, when I deleted the last post in that node the node disappeared, when i created a new post they node would not reappear.

I went back to an old backup of my app that did create the post node no problem but it still does not create the node in my realtime database.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Please add code of the part where you are creating node and posts.

Comment: renamed posts to upload and it recreate the node, that's how it was fixed for anyone else that ever has this problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what this code is supposed to do that exactly doesn't work the way you expect. Please respond using @AlexMamo